# Write comment to excel-cell and autofit the comment-box?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

i was able to add a comment to an excel-cell using the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets[0]
ws.range("A1").api.AddComment(Text="My Comment")
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Is it possible to autofit the size of the comment-box somehow in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean enable the `'Automatic size'` option for comments in `Format Comments`? If so you need to enable that with;

```
.Shape.DrawingObject.AutoSize
```

in the cell comment properties.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets[0]
ws.range("A1").api.AddComment(Text="My Comment")
ws.range("A1").api.Comment.Shape.DrawingObject.AutoSize = True
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

This would change the text formatting like so;
If I used the text:-

```
Text="i was able to add a comment to an excel-cell using the following code:\n
     Is it possible to autofit the size of the comment-box somehow in excel?"
```

Cell A1 has AutoSize enabled 
Cell A4 is how the comment looks as default where Autosize is disabled.

[image: Example]

You can also set the specific height and width of the comment box. Obviously in this case it would mean making a guestimation and sizing based on the text you were entering.

Comment: It seems that work great on windows. But it is also able to work on MacOS:
Currentlky i get this error on MacOS: AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'AddComment'